# C++ compiling problem; class methods

Tags: c++, class, compiler-construction, methods

I have started writing a very simple class, and all kinds of class methods seem to give me problems. I hope the problem is me and the solution is simple.

The command g++ -o main main.cpp gives the folowing output:

```
/usr/bin/ld: Undefined symbols:
Lexer::ConsoleWriteTokens()
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

main.cpp:

```
#include<iostream>
#include"lexer.h"


int main(){

   Lexer lexhnd = Lexer();
    std::cout << "RAWR\n";
    lexhnd.ConsoleWriteTokens();
   std::cout << "\n\n";

return 0;
 }
```

lexer.h:

```
#ifndef __SCRIPTLEXER
#define __SCRIPTLEXER

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#define DEF_TOKEN_KEYWORD 0

struct token{
 int flag;
 std::string data;
};

class Lexer
{
public:
//  bool IsTrue();
//  bool AddLine(char * line);
    void ConsoleWriteTokens(void);

private:
std::vector<token> TOK_list;

};


#endif
```

lexer.cpp:

```
bool Lexer::IsTrue(){
return true;
};


 bool Lexer::AddLine(char * line){

token cool;
cool.data = line;

TOK_list.push_back(cool);
string = line;
return true;
};

void Lexer::ConsoleWriteTokens(void){

for (int i = 0; i < TOK_list.size(); i++){
    std::cout << "TOKEN! " << i;
}

return 0;
};
```

I am using g++ in xcode btw.

Thankyou very much in advance, I have been on this problem for a few hours.

EDIT:

```
g++ -o main lexer.h main.cpp
or
g++ -o main lexer.cpp main.cpp
or
g++ -o main main.cpp lexer.cpp
```

do NOT work either. 
-Hyperzap

Comment: +1 for including the error, the command you used to compile and a minimal example.  A very nice question.

Comment: I think, you should learn to write Makefiles or use automake/autoconf or cmake or qmake or use an IDE that will do any of that for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your not compiling the lexer.cpp code.

Try

```
g++ -o main main.cpp lexer.cpp
```

as your compilation command.

**PROBLEMS IN THE lexer.cpp**

You probably want to include the lexer header in the lexer.cpp file

```
#include "lexer.h"
```

Also, you don't want to return an integer from void functions.

```
void Lexer::ConsoleWriteTokens(void){
  for (int i = 0; i < TOK_list.size(); i++){
    std::cout << "TOKEN! " << i;
  }
  //This function is void - it shouldn't return something
  //return 0;
};
```

Finally, you have some problems withs this function

```
bool Lexer::AddLine(char * line){

  token cool;
  cool.data = line;

  TOK_list.push_back(cool);
  //what is this next line trying to achieve?  
  //string = line;
  return true;
};
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with the line I commented out, 
it doesn't seem to do anything and string isn't defined (did you mean `std::string mystring = line;`)

Finally, don't forget to uncomment the functions declaired in `lexer.h` that you are defining in `lexer.cpp`.

Comment: also, when you compile multiple .cpp in the command line as you have shown, is it 'compiling' the code, and then joining them together, or do you have to link lexer.cpp to main.cpp using #include "lexer.h" in main.cpp???

Comment: @hyperzap It does it all for you.  Your original error was a linker error - the linker couldn't find Lexer::ConsoleWriteTokens() although all the code that it had was correct.  When you added lexer.cpp you got additional compilation errors (because some of the code was wrong).  When you fixed those errors the linker got to work again and was happy because it could now find your methods definitions.

Answer (score 2):

Include all the .cpp files in the command line, like this:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp lexer.cpp
```

When your project grows, it becomes wise to manage your project in some automatic way: Makefiles, ant, or some IDE-integrated project file.

Comment: You must include `lexer.h` from `lexer.cpp`. The compiler will start over with each source file, each source file must include the header files it needs.

Comment: excellent thankyou. funny that, I thought it was the other way around, where you 'chain' all your scripts together using #include., instead of compiling separately and linking. Not to mention I forgot to put the #include back in after removing in experimentation angst.

Answer (score 1):

Well `g++ -o main main.cpp lexer.cpp` sould do the trick. However I suggest making makefile files. When having a multiple amount of file they come in handy. 
I would also suggest adding some optimization to your compilation like -O3 or -O2 (O is a letter o not zero digit!). The difference in execution speed is very noticable. Also if you are goig to make libraries out of your files, why not using --shared option that will create a liked library. I find making shared libraries very useful.

Comment: +1 Yes, you should definately use scripts to help you build your files.  I would try to learn cmake from the beginning - its cross platform and so will work in both linux and windows.  autotools is a (very common) linux tool only.